# Make a call from application contact info screen

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I want to make a call from my windows mobile application one of user's contact information detail page.

I searched and come up with one link but not able to reach its code.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb278110.aspx
```

Can any one help for the same?

Answer (score 0):

the download file is no more available.

Possibly we can help, if you just describe what you want to do.

The above article is very long and shows many functions.

~josef